# Chromecast receiver for OSX

Tags: streaming, chromecast

Is there a working Chromecast receiver for OSX. ie I could send audio or video from a phone or another PC to stream on there laptop?

I know there were some experiments previously, but not sure anything is working now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several options include:

- [Reflector 2](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/features/mac/)
- [AirServer Universal](https://www.airserver.com)

And if you feel brave and are able to compile Python, [LeapCast](https://github.com/dz0ny/leapcast) may be an option.

Hope this helps.

Comment: looks like LeapCast is no longer work